# How to get Joining an IQueryable with model any types sql c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this model `ExpenseReport`

```
public class ExpenseReport
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid InternalId { get; set; }
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public bool IsDraft { get; set; }
        public int BaseCurrencyId { get; set; }
        public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
        public Guid? JobId { get; set; }
        public Job Job { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PublishedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ExpectedPayDate { get; set; }
        public ExpenseReportStatus Status { get; set; }
        public ExpenseReportStatusEnum StatusId { get; set; }
        public string OriginReference { get; set; }
        public decimal AdvanceValue { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalValue { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

I Need to Join to get `JOB, CUSTOMER,` and `Contact` from another table

when I use `LINQ` to get these values ​​it returns me `null` them. What would be the junction of this return

My query

```
  public IQueryable<ExpenseReport> ExpenseReports => (from exReport in _dataContext.ExpenseReport
                                                            join job in _dataContext.Job on exReport.JobId equals job.Id
                                                            join contact in _dataContext.Contact on exReport.ContactId equals contact.Id
                                                            join customer in _dataContext.Customer on exReport.CustomerId equals customer.Id
                                                            select exReport );
```

Comment: It is unclear which implementation of `IQueryable` you are using. The answer is different depending on if you are using `EntityFramework`, `Linq2SQL`, `nHibernate`, `OData` etc...

Comment: I using  EntityFramework with SQL server

Comment: If you are using EntityFramework, you should NEVER use the join keyword. Your EDM should be configured such that your `ExpenseReport` class has a `ExpenseReport.Job`, `ExpenseReport.Customer` and `ExpenseReport.Contact` navigation property. Furthermore, your Linq is wrong in that you only select out the `ExpenseReport`. In SQL terms you are doing `Select A.* from A join B on...`.

Comment: What better way to bring data, without me exposing the same. Do I need to bring only JOBNAME, would I have to use INCLUDE and bring only Name property?

Comment: Depends on where you are writing your code. For proper reusability any library code should just return the `IQueryable<ExpenseReport>`. Only in the consumer business logic should you make the projection on `ExpenseReport.Job.Name` possibly with an anonymous class.

Comment: configuration is done in configEntity. My business rule is to bring only a few job fields, such as name and ID. Because I can not expose daods. I'm stuck.
I do not know if this is correct   .Include(x => x.Job).Select(required)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193970/discussion-between-aron-and-eliemerson-fonseca).

Comment: it is not true that you should never use the join keyword. the join keyword (or extension method) is the easiest method to implement an inner join or to join on columns that are not keys. For the most likely required left outer joins on FK=PK it is true however, that no "manual" join is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to create a `DTO` that only returns that I need and use `.Include`

```js
var ownerData = _repository.ExpenseReports
                .Where(w => w.AccountId.Equals(_identityService.Identity.CurrentAccount.Id))
                .Include(x => x.Customer)
                .Include(x => x.Job)
                .Select(x => new MyExpenseReportDTO
                {
                   Id = x.Id,
                   InternalId = x.InternalId,
                   Alias = x.Alias,
                   Job = x.Job.Name,
                   CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn,
                   ExpectedPayDate = x.ExpectedPayDate,
                   Customer = x.Customer.Name,
                   CostCenterName = x.Job.CostCenter.Name,
                   BaseCurrencyId = x.BaseCurrencyId,
                   Status = x.Status.Name,
                   TotalValue = x.TotalValue
                });
```

Comment: Yes, IMO using DTOs is the best choice most of the times. Note that because of the `Select` the `Includes` are redundant now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following in your business class

```
var results = from report in _context.ExpenseReport
              select new { Report = report, JobName = report.Job.Name };
foreach(var x in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Got job {x.JobName} with { x.Report }");
}
```